# Incluir un modulo propio en otro Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-material

Mi pregunta es:
¿Como puedo importar modulos de Angular material en un modulo propio, y luego ese modulo importarlo en app.module.ts?.

Este es mi modulo personal:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatButtonModule
    ],
    declarations: [

    ]
})

export class MaterialModule { }
```

con lo cual yo lo que hago es lo siguiente en app.module.ts:

```
import {MaterialModule} from './material.module';
```

imports array:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    MaterialModule
  ],
```

El caso es que recibo errores, pero si lo hago directamente todo en app.module.ts me funciona. No quiero tener todo importado en un mismo modulo, para no hacerlo dificil a la hora de revisar, o corregir código.
Gracias de antemano, un saludo.

Comment: Deberías añadir el código de ambos módulos y los errores que se te muestran en la pregunta, en principio la importación es transitiva y no debería darte problemas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes exportar los módulos también para que puedan ser usados en diferentes módulos, solo debes agregar un arreglo con la propiedad exports a tu NgModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MatMenuModule,
        MatButtonModule
    ],
    declarations: [

    ],
    exports:[
        MatMenuModule,
        MatButtonModule
    ]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! Era eso.tengo manía de buscar la solución a problemas complicandome más de la cuenta, cuando en realidad era simplemente eso. Gracias.